# Create different views for different users for the same object(i.e hide some fields from some users)

Tags: custom-object, trigger

Is it possible to allow different users to populate fields of the same object but from different views(or "tabs") such that they only see the details they are supposed to populate.
Eg An object has the following fields:
Name
Email
Fees Paid
Outstanding fees
Grade
Dorm
I want one user (Say the secretary of a school) to fill in the email and Name.
Another user (Say the Accountant) will fill in the fees paid and outstanding fees while the teacher fills in the grade and dorm, but you only want each to see just the fields they are to populate(ideally from a different "tab") i.e is it possible to have the different views for the different users as separate objects(what I'm referring to as "tab")?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to show/hide fields based on Profiles. 
Go to Administer > Security Controls > Field Accessibility.
[image]